# Youtube API v3 ASR Caption Extraction

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on an app that needs to pull caption data for Youtube videos, in particular ASR captions. I am using the Youtube v3 API to do this. However, when I send a GET request to pull caption data from a video ID (caption_list), I am told,

"The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption."

My question is if there is a way to pull captions from videos with ASR captions with the Youtube API (for which I have a client ID, a client secret, and an API key) without being the owner of the video. I need this to be done via an HTTP request and not a local download, as I intent to open the caption file and do other things with it via python code

Thanks!

Comment: I tried to get ASR captions for a video I uploaded and got a similar error. I don't think this can be done via HTTP request. What happens when you try it using the [sample code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download#examples)? Also, I don't see any way in the documentation to get the captions without downloading them.

Comment: here is the working link `http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=yJXTXN4xrI8` and you can add `&track=asr` in URL to get ASR Caption, and do you have found how you can upload and done auto transcription by youtube V3 API.